# Implementing patch for changing a CPU frequency governor

Tags: linux, patch

I need implement patch for changing a CPU frequency governor.But I don't know what is patch and Governor in Linux and I don't know where I can start from?

Comment: Governor of **what**?

Comment: @ peterph I want change Governor of Powersave .please help me

Comment: jeez, why is it called a governor ?

Comment: @foampile I edit my question .any idea?

Comment: I am confident your question would receive a better response if you could manage to more fully describe what you are doing. This implies also that you give some information about what Governer you mean. The same thing is true for the patch you want to implement. You need to tell what source code you intent to patch. Sometimes it is hard and you are a beginner so I hope you keep face and manage to express you question in a way that will generate you some help. People here are helpful, but have trouble understanding you, I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the CPU frequency governor (which of course affects the overall battery time), you need to write to files located in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuN/cpufreq` (at least that's where they tend to be on most systems with not-too-old kernels), where N is the number of the CPU core. `scaling_available_governors` contains a list of available governors. You can use one of those by writing its name to `scaling_governor`. No need for C/C++, shell one-liner

```
echo {selected_governor} > /sys/.../cpufreq
```

is sufficient. Be aware, that on a multicore machine it can change stuff for more than one and/or not all CPUs (get a list from the `affected_cpus` file).

The easiest (and safest) way, is to use [cpufreq-utils](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/cpufreq/).