# how implement patch for change a arbitrary Governor in linux

Tags: linux, patch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing patch for changing a CPU frequency governor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59570/implementing-patch-for-changing-a-cpu-frequency-governor)

I am beginner in linux.I want implement a patch for change a arbitrary Governor in linux.not important what Governor be it.I only want some example for this work.thanks

Comment: This same question [was closed earlier](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59570/implementing-patch-for-changing-a-cpu-frequency-governor): please do not do this again...